# How to make an API response become a global variable to use again in subsequent API request

Tags: node.js

Here is the code

```
request.post({
    headers: {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    url: "https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?",
    form: 
        {requestType: "sendMoney"}
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            var transactionBytes = JSON.parse(response.body).transactionBytes;
        }
    },
);
```

I would like to take transactionBytes and pass it into another API request after this. How do I make it a global variable? I tried global.transactionBytes and window.transactionBytes and that didn't work. I have also read that is bad to declare a global variable like this, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why declare it as a global? Right where you're assigning it, just go ahead and call your next function and pass it as a param..

Comment: Fair point... I did it and it worked. It looks a little cluttered but maybe I just need to get over that. How many nested API calls would a developer usually use before breaking them apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just one file you can declare global variable just declaring out side of your function.

```
var globalvariable = 0;

function ApiCall() {
request.post({
    headers: {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    url: "https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?",
    form: 
        {requestType: "sendMoney"}
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            var transactionBytes = JSON.parse(response.body).transactionBytes;
        }
    },
);
}
```

if you want to use same global variable in multiple files, you can create a helper file example

help.js

```
var globalVariable = 0;
module.exports = globalVariable
```

firstfile.js

```
var globalVariable = require('./help');
   function ApiCall() {
    request.post({
        headers: {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
        url: "https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?",
        form: 
            {requestType: "sendMoney"}
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                var transactionBytes = JSON.parse(response.body).transactionBytes;
                globalVariable = transactionBytes;
            }
        },
    );
    }
```

anotherfile.js

```
var globalVariable = require('./help');
function someotherthing() {
  console.log(globalVariable)
}
```

Using a global variable is bad unless really required, other way is just passing the value to next function. Global variable can cause memory leaks if not used properly